# How to develop modern telnet applications (accessed thru remote terminals)?

Tags: terminal, telnet, application-server

given my current scenario where I have a device and it only has a telnet client for me to use, what are the options as of today for developing applications that will be accessed thru telnet? Are there any frameworks that can help achieving this? How do I host them?

Comment: All you really need is a network socket where you can read characters. Whenever you receive a newline then you parse the line. No need for a framework (unless you want some for the actual networking part, and maybe something to help you with parsing). Just because you have to connect through a telnet client doesn't mean you have to handle all the "telnetty" bits.

Comment: Thanks for your input Joachim, but what I meant was the possibility of having more options to enhance interactivity on the terminal, not only creating a command based parsing solution type.

Comment: If you mean like reacting to a single key-press, then yes that's possible. I don't know any about framework though (and it's off-topic to ask for links to such here on StackOverflow anyway, not to mention impossible since you don't tell us what programming language and platform you use anyway)..However, implementing the telnet state machine is not that hard really. It might be a lot of lines of code, but most of it is really simple and basic.[Read the RFCs (the standards)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs).

Comment: Thanks again Joachim for your patience! :) Today we have decides that only have telnet clients on them and we use oracle forms 6 on caracter mode on a linux server. What I really wanted is to know any other technology who could give me the same interactivity I have using oracle forms thru telnet. I am really open to use any other more modern technology and platform. Thanks again for your response!